# Jenkins CI - automate execution of tests using TestObject's Gradle Build Plugin

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I am trying to automate the execution of my Espresso tests using TestObject's Gradle build plugin (see: https://testobject.com/blog/2015/11/testobject-gradle-plugin.html). I have modified my gradle.build file like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://nexus.testobject.org/nexus/content/repositories/testobject-public-repo' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12+'
        classpath group: 'org.testobject', name: 'testobject-gradle-plugin', version: '0.0.39'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'testobject'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.appname"
        // For production release, this should be v17
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1.7"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

testobject {
    username "username"
    password "password"
    team "team-name"
    app "app-name"
    testSuite 8
    runAsPackage true
    failOnUnknown true
    sizes = ["small","medium","large"]
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

But when I run "gradle build" it doesn't create a folder "testobject" within the "build" directory like specified in the documentation. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this? Any other suggestion (/tutorial) on how to automate my tests using TestObject/Jenkins CI would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different build directories in Android projects. One of them is under the project root and the other one is under the `app` directory. We create the XMLs under the second one. You can easily find the folder if you run this command in the root folder of your project:

```
find * -type d | grep testobject
```

Just to help you a bit further, I would recommend you not to set the `runAsPackage` configuration, since that is only recommended to customers who use their custom Test Runner. Sizes configuration is also not needed if you just want to run all your tests.